# When watching a direcory via grunt-contrib-watch, how can I retrieve the name of the file that changed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Say I have a directory of CSS files and my Grunt watch task is configured like this:

```
watch: {
    css: {
        files: ['css/*.css'],
        tasks: ['foo']
    }
}
```

where `foo` is my own custom task:

```
grunt.registerTask('foo', function () {
    // but which file changed?
});
```

So, whenever any of the CSS files in that directory changes, Grunt will invoke my `foo` task. I would like to retrieve the file name of the affected CSS file (the file that changed) from within my task. I hope this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

The task emits a watch event that you can listen for. There's an example in the [readme](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch):

```
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
  grunt.log.writeln(target + ': ' + filepath + ' has ' + action);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I've found it. This seems to be the only way to retrieve the file name. I'm not happy with this code pattern though, but I have no choice but to use it it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution in the README file of the watch plugin:

```
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
  grunt.log.writeln(target + ': ' + filepath + ' has ' + action);
});
```

So, whenever the watch task is triggered, it fires a `"watch"` event. This enables us to handle that event and retrieve the file name of the changed file which is provided as the second argument. I've checked and this event handler will run *before* the task set in the configuration for the watch task (`foo` in my code above), so we're golden.

**Commentary:** I was hoping for a more streamlined solution though. Why can't the watch task provide the file name directly to the task that it invokes via an argument? This "watch" handler isn't the optimal code pattern IMO.

Comment: Check out this proposed way to streamline it better: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/263

Comment: @KyleRobinsonYoung I've posted a comment. I've added grunt-newer to one of my watch tasks just yesterday. Works great; seems like a better approach than what is being proposed.